# Replacing window.showModalDialog from all javascript

Tags: javascript

I have my javascript file in which I have used `window.showModalDialog` in many places. Replacing it with `window.open etc`. at every place is practically impossible for me.

*Is there any way I can achieve this in a generic way?*

Answer (score 0):

Can you just redefine window.showModalDialog to suit your needs:

```
window.showModalDialog = function(url) {
    window.open(url)
}
```

Then your old code will work with new functionality.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7t9gw71/

Without seeing your code, I don't know exactly what you want to do, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

Good luck.